# Login page displayed even if the user is already logged in

Tags: python, django, authentication

I use Django's authentication view `django.contrib.auth.views.login` to log in my users.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)
```

[Here is the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) regarding this functionality.

**My problem:** The login page is displayed even if the user is already connected.

Comment: Do you check if user.is_authenticated to disable login page?

Answer (score 2):

For django 2.x, you can simply do this

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the contrib login view with your own modifications in your own view.  Just change the login url to point to your own view, then check if they are already logged in:

---

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as contrib_login

def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    return contrib_login(request)
```

Comment: Good idea, it will probably work. But where should I put the file views.py since it's not supposed to be linked to any application in my Django project? Should I create an application called "authentication" or should I just create a views.py file in my my_site directory (where settings.py and global urls.py live)?

Comment: I suppose it would be up to you.  I generally create a 'core' application with things like this.